# startActivity not working in android

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I have not been able to find a solution to my problem that works, so here it is:

When I play this code the debugger shows the startActivity statement is reached, but then execution just passes over it.

Java code:

```
public class grassesDoFamily extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected String TAG = "grassesDoFamily >>";
    private String  familyName;
    private String  familyText;
    private int     familyNumber;
    private String  familyTable;
    private int     genusNumber;
    private int     speciesNumber;

    Context dContext = grassesDoFamily.this;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.grasses_layout_start_family);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        familyNumber = myIntent.getIntExtra("familyNumber", 0);
        genusNumber = myIntent.getIntExtra("genusNumber", 0);
        speciesNumber = myIntent.getIntExtra("speciesNumber", 0);
        /**
         *      Get Family data
         */
        GetFamily(familyNumber);
        /**
         *  Special case fam=5 : generic, fam=4 Plantaginaceae
         */
       // Intent intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain = new Intent(dContext, grassesShowSpeciesMain.class);

        Intent intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain = new Intent(dContext, grassesShowSpeciesMain.class);
        /**
         *  Get genus# and species# if not Plantaginaceae
         */
       if (familyNumber==5){

            intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("genusNumber", genusNumber);
            intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("speciesNumber", speciesNumber);

        }
        if ((familyNumber==5) || (familyNumber==4)){


            intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("familyNumber", familyNumber);
            startActivity(intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain);
        }
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.learningideas.grasses.grassesShowSpeciesMain"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/doShowSpecies"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName="com.learningideas.grasses.grassesActivityMain">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.learningideas.grasses.grassesActivityMain" />
</activity>
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post your grassesShowSpeciesMain

Comment: Any error or something strange happens? Or it's just doing anything?

Comment: Intent intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain = new Intent(grassDoFamily.this, grassesShowSpeciesMain.class);
You nees to point Activity, not Context...

Comment: `dContext` is the activity itself. Check its initialization: `Context dContext = grassesDoFamily.this`

Comment: can you post your `grassesShowSpeciesMain` class ?

Comment: Tried it with the following code for grassesShowSpeciesMain:

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grasses_layout_do_species);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    }


}

Does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the odd Context member variable you are using. Try simplifying to:

```
Intent intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain = new Intent(this,grassesShowSpeciesMain.class);
```

Comment: `dContext` is defined as `Context dContext = grassesDoFamily.this` so if that's the problem it would be a very odd one

Answer (score -1):

You should change this to:

```
if (familyNumber == 5) {
    intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("genusNumber", genusNumber);
    intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("speciesNumber", speciesNumber);
}
else if (familyNumber == 4) {
    intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain.putExtra("familyNumber", familyNumber);
}
if (familyNumber == 5 || familyNumber == 4) {
    startActivity(intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain);
}
```

Comment: It's the same problem as @Anil response

Comment: why? it is not.

Comment: It is indeed. Your code will launch the activity even if `familyNumber == 0`

Comment: Again, not correct. If `familyNumber == 5` that data should be passed to the activity. Just think a little bit before launching answers...

Comment: @Pelocho can I understand what the is the desired output?

Comment: I just removed all conditional statements and so the startActivity(intentgrassesShowSpeciesMain) is executed right after the declaration. Does not help: the debugger shows I reach the startAcitivity statement and then just passes over it.